# how to solve No matching client found for package name '

Tags: java, android-studio

Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project D:\Profile\AGAINAGAIN

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>
> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED
>   Parsing json file: D:\Profile\AGAINAGAIN\app\google-services.json

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > No matching client found for package name 'com.Dinke.againagain'

Any solution provided ?Please tell me if you know any of the files . 
Since I think every cases are unique, I think it is better to provide as much info as I can ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the  google-services.json change the package name to your package name;

```
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.Dinke.againagain" //here
        }
      },
```

You can read more about this here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#processing_the_json_file

Comment: Could you tell why this can solve the problems ?Please